# user input isn't working with greater than in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to create a program in python that will determine which number is bigger from two user inputted numbers. For some reason, python is telling me that the smaller number is greater than the larger number. It seems to work correctly if I input only single digit numbers or only double digit numbers, but not if I input a single and a double digit number.

```
a=input("Enter an int:\n")
b=input("Enter another int:\n")


if a>b:
    print(a+" is greater than " + b)
elif b>a:
    print(b+" is greater than " + a)
```

If I input 10 for a and 3 for b then I get the output: `3 is greater than 10`

If I input 6 for a and 2 for b then I get the output: `6 is greater than 2`

If I input 24 for a and 10 for b then I get the output: `24 is greater than 10`

Why does it not work with a single and a double digit?

Comment: _Why does it not work with a single and a double digit?_ Because `input()` returns a **string** value, and strings use **alphabetic** comparison instead of **numeric** comparison.  Convert the input values to integer using the `int()` function like this `a = int(input("Enter an int:"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's built-in input() function always returns a str(string) class object. Therefore, for taking integer input, we have to type cast those inputs into integers by using the built-in function int(). See revised below:

```
a=int(input("Enter an int:\n"))
b=int(input("Enter another int:\n"))
```

However, in order to let the print statements work, you have to adjust them as well. Now you are trying to make a joint string from a string and an integer, which will lead to an TypeError. Therefore, you can try:

```
if a>b:
    print("{} is greater than {}".format(a,b))
elif b>a:
    print("{} is greater than {}".format(b,a))
```

So the full code will be:

```
a=int(input("Enter an int:\n"))
b=int(input("Enter another int:\n"))


if a>b:
    print("{} is greater than {}".format(a,b))
elif b>a:
    print("{} is greater than {}".format(b,a))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a cleaner way of doing this, you can use f-strings to format your output:

```
# Accept user inputs and convert to integer
a = int(input("Enter an int:\n"))
b = int(input("Enter another int:\n"))

# Check for the greater number and print a formatted output using f-strings.
if a > b:
    print(f"{a} is greater than {b}.")
elif b > a:
    print(f"{b} is greater than {a}.")
```